# pdb.set_trace() for powershell to jump into the debugger interactive console

Tags: python, powershell

Is there a equivalent in powershell of the python pdb.set_trace()?

I want to be able to stop execution of the script at a specific line and then jump into the debugger interactive console. (I would prefer not having to use ISE)

I've seen that there's a Set-PSBreakpoint, but on that one needs to specify the script and line.

Comment: Use `Set-PSBreakPoint` and `$MyInvocation` to set the breakpoint on the next line of the current script? (With a little care and getting the outer scope's `$MyInvocation` this could be done in a helper.)

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is

```
$Host.EnterNestedPrompt()
```

Just the one line. Your script will stop there and you'll be given a shell where you can inspect variables, etc. When you're done, you just exit your nested shell and execution resumes. I used to sometimes leave these statements lying around, though, so now I always:

```
######## DEBUG ##########
$Host.EnterNestedPrompt()
######## END DEBUG ##########
```

So I can easily find (and remove) them when I'm done with them.

Comment: Wow. This is a life saver. How did I manage to live without it?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so the equivalent in powershell of python's pdb.set_trace() is:

```
function Set-Trace {
  Set-PSBreakPoint -Line ($MyInvocation.ScriptLineNumber + 1) -Script $MyInvocation.ScriptName
}
```

However, unlike in python, in powershell once you install the trace it'll be there forever until you kill your powershell session. I recommend adding this to the beginning of your script to remove old traces:

```
function Remove-AllTraces {
  Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint
}
```

Many thanks to @Richard's suggestion. :)